# How can I use @Value in Spring Boot application with Gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, yaml

I have `storeId: store5` in application.yml (src/main/ressource)
in Java class

```
@Service
public class RefundServiceImpl implements RefundService {

    @Value("${storeId}")
    String storeId;
```

when I start main I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'storeId' in value "${storeId}"
```

Comment: build;gradle
processResources {
    with copySpec {
        from 'src/main/resources'
        include '**/application*.yml'
        include '**/application*.yaml'
        include '**/application*.properties'
        project.properties.findAll().each {
            prop ->
                if (prop.value != null) {
                    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [ (prop.key): prop.value])
                    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [ ('project.' + prop.key): prop.value])
                }
        }
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

Comment: do you have an application.properties file inside /src/main/resources? If you do, then just add storeId=15 (or whatever you want to) to that file.

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead. See also [ask].

Comment: Is the file literally in `src/main/ressource`? If so, move it to `src/main/resources`